# SUM values if two conditions are met in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi I have been working on some SQL code to sum up three different values given that certain conditions are met. However, I've been running into issues and would like some help.

Here is a visual of the table that I have now:

```
Row | Transaction_date | Loss | Estimated_value | Average_value
 1  | 19960105         | Y    | 10578604.234    | 485950.235
 2  | 19960105         | N    | 230405.34       | 453835.53
 3  | 19960105         | N    | 755443.467      | 59694.43
 4  | 19970107         | Y    | 506040.564      | 45345.45
 5  | 19970107         | N    | 45345354.35     | 79594.246
 6  | 19970107         | N    | 3453500.234     | 83674.342
```

I want to add the numbers in the Estimated_value and Average_value columns together if the Loss = N and when the Transaction_date is the same. For example, I would want to avoid adding rows 2 and 5 together since they have different transaction dates.

Desired result:

```
Row | Transaction_date | Loss | Estimated_value | Average_value
 1  | 19960105         | Y    | 10578604.234    | 485950.235
 2  | 19960105         | N    | 985848.807      | 513529.96
 3  | 19970107         | Y    | 506040.564      | 45345.45
 4  | 19970107         | N    | 48798854.584    | 163268.588
```

I have tried using union all and sum(case when ... then ...) but they do not seem to work.

Thank you for the help.

I have tried the solution from @Ben.S
This does not seem to work as intended. Here is the code I have adapted from the response:

```
SELECT TRANSACTION_DATE
,LOSS
,NEWTOTALLOSSFLAG AS TOTALLOSSFLAG
,ESTIMATEVOLUME
,SUMTOTAL
,AVERAGETOTAL
FROM T2
WHERE NEWTOTALLOSSFLAG = 'Y'

UNION

SELECT TRANSACTION_DATE
,LOSS
,NEWTOTALLOSSFLAG AS TOTALLOSSFLAG
,SUM(ESTIMATEVOLUME) AS ESTIMATEVOLUME
,SUM(SUMTOTAL) AS SUMTOTAL
,SUM(AVERAGETOTAL) AS AVERAGETOTAL
FROM T2
WHERE NEWTOTALLOSSFLAG = 'N'
GROUP BY TRANSACTION_DATE, LOSSCATEGORYCODE
ORDER BY TRANSACTION_DATE;
```

The result is ORA-000936 missing expression.

Comment: Please add the desired result based on your data sample to your question. It will also be helpful if you post your best try to write such query.

Comment: do you want to sum (Estimated_value) by itself and sum(Average_value) by itself
from different rows that have the same  Transaction_date ?

Comment: @Ben.S yes. I have edited my post to reflect the desired result.

Comment: @wasd777 do you have just one row with `loss='Y'` per each `Transaction_date` or is it possible that you may have few rows with the same  `Transcation_date` and 'Loss='Y'`?

Comment: @wasd777 I have simplified my answer, I would appreciate if you can mark my answer as answered, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Is this helps

```
 SELECT Transaction_date, Loss, Estimated_value, Average_value  
 FROM table_name 
 WHERE Loss = 'Y'  
 
 UNION

 SELECT Transaction_date, Loss, SUM(Estimated_value) AS Estimated_value, 
        SUM (Average_value) AS Average_value 
 FROM table_name
 WHERE Loss = 'N'
 GROUP BY Transaction_date, Loss
 ORDER BY Transaction_date
```

**EDIT**

**Because there is no duplicate value of `Loss = 'Y'` per a giving `Transaction_date`** you can simplify the query to this:

```
SELECT Transaction_date, Loss, SUM(Estimated_value) AS Estimated_value, 
       SUM (Average_value) AS Average_value 
FROM table_name    
GROUP BY Transaction_date, Loss
ORDER BY Transaction_date
```

(and because of that there is also no need to the `DECODE` function as suggested by @SayanMalakshinov)

Comment: This only shows the sums of the values with Loss = N. I want to maintain the values with Loss = Y as well (just not summed).

Comment: I am getting the error "ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression"

Comment: @wasd777 do you have multiple `loss = 'Y'` values per a giving `Transaction_date`? and try omitting the brackets from the ROW column

Comment: I do not. I only have multiple ```loss = 'N'``` values. I will try the above.

Comment: @wasd777 if so you can omit the entire group by clause in the first select, edited the answer

Comment: @wasd777 what is the result you are getting ?

Comment: This does not seem to work as intended. Here is the code I have adapted from your response: 
``` SELECT TRANSACTION_DATE
,LOSS
,NEWTOTALLOSSFLAG AS TOTALLOSSFLAG
,ESTIMATEVOLUME
,SUMTOTAL
,AVERAGETOTAL
FROM T2
WHERE NEWTOTALLOSSFLAG = 'Y'

UNION

SELECT TRANSACTION_DATE
,LOSS
,NEWTOTALLOSSFLAG AS TOTALLOSSFLAG
,SUM(ESTIMATEVOLUME) AS ESTIMATEVOLUME
,SUM(SUMTOTAL) AS SUMTOTAL
,SUM(AVERAGETOTAL) AS AVERAGETOTAL
FROM T2
WHERE NEWTOTALLOSSFLAG = 'N'
GROUP BY TRANSACTION_DATE, LOSSCATEGORYCODE
ORDER BY TRANSACTION_DATE; ```
The result is ORA-000936 missing expression.

Comment: @wasd777 all columns in the select most be in the group by clause or in an aggregate function is this the situation ?

Comment: Actually, I believe getting rid of the first group by statement fixed the issue. Thank you!

Comment: @wasd777 can you please accept my answer ?

Comment: `UNION` is useful in very rare cases when it is allowed to have the same rows in some of the parts. In general you should use `UNION ALL` to avoid unnecessary duplicate reduction. Also in case of no duplicates per transaction and `Y` flag all the query can be reduced to single `select` with just a group by.

Answer (score 0):

You can get what you want using this simple SQL trick:

```sql
select
    Transaction_date
   ,Loss
   ,sum(Estimated_value ) as Estimated_value
   ,sum(Average_value   ) as Average_value
from t2
group by Transaction_date, Loss, decode(Loss,'Y',rownum,0)
order by Transaction_date, Loss;
```

I've just added `decode(Loss,'Y',rownum,0)` into `group by` clause to place each row with Loss='Y' into different groups, but all rows with Loss='N' will be in one group. I.e. this `decode()` will return different [`rownum`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/ROWNUM-Pseudocolumn.html) for rows with `Loss='Y'` and 0 for rows with `Loss='N'`.

Obviously, you can replace `decode(Loss,'Y',rownum,0)` with ANSI-compatible `case` statement: `case Loss when 'Y' then rownum else 0 end`.

Full test case with sample data:

```sql
alter session set nls_date_format='yyyymmdd';

with t2(Transaction_date , Loss , Estimated_value , Average_value) as (
    select to_date('19960105','yyyymmdd'), 'Y', 10578604.234    , 485950.235 from dual union all
    select to_date('19960105','yyyymmdd'), 'N', 230405.34       , 453835.53  from dual union all
    select to_date('19960105','yyyymmdd'), 'N', 755443.467      , 59694.43   from dual union all
    select to_date('19970107','yyyymmdd'), 'Y', 506040.564      , 45345.45   from dual union all
    select to_date('19970107','yyyymmdd'), 'N', 45345354.35     , 79594.246  from dual union all
    select to_date('19970107','yyyymmdd'), 'N', 3453500.234     , 83674.342  from dual
)
select
    Transaction_date
   ,Loss
   ,sum(Estimated_value ) as Estimated_value
   ,sum(Average_value   ) as Average_value
from t2
group by Transaction_date, Loss, decode(Loss,'Y',rownum,0)
order by Transaction_date, Loss;
```

Results:

```sql
TRANSACTION_DATE    LOSS ESTIMATED_VALUE AVERAGE_VALUE
------------------- ---- --------------- -------------
19960105            N         985848.807     513529.96
19960105            Y         10578604.2    485950.235
19970107            N         48798854.6    163268.588
19970107            Y         506040.564      45345.45
```